# SASS: shared between apps

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, sass

Context: webplatform aggregating multiple react apps. Each app has its .scss files. 
I would like to extract the common .scss somehow (in a library maybe?). Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Worth mentioning: i already have a private library for the shared components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! Just pack it with the library you mentioned it as NPM package or local NPM package and import directly from there like.

NOTE: Don't compile the SCSS file

```css
@import "~/your-package/scss/file";
```